# open iframe src to new page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My web page opens app.html first.After clicking to login i need to open index.html which i open in iframe and i dynamically create iframe in javascript.so to open that i frame im appending to document.body.But it appends to the body of the app.html.But I need to open in new page

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
el.setAttribute('name', 'ifrm');
el.setAttribute('src', '/index/index.html');
el.setAttribute('width', '100%');
el.setAttribute('height', '100%');
el.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing... are you trying to open index.html N ADDITION to the original app.html, as a popup, as a new tab, or in the SAME window/tab/frame - in other words to replace it?  Please provide a little more info and we can help you better.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this to open in a new window:

```
var myWindow = window.open("/index/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to layer the iframe over the current page

el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.top = 0;
el.style.left = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do.  The answer all depends on things like:

1. Are you trying to open `index.html` **in addition** to `app.html` or instead of it?

   1. If you want both open, then do you want to open in a new window?

      1. If so, do you want a regular window (i.e. same size as the original, without modification).  Yes, then use JavaScript:

         > newWin = window.open("index.html", "My App's Main Window", winOptions);
      2. or a specific size window, with other modifications (*no Navigation bar, No address bar, etc*) - in other words do you want a **Popup Window**

         > ```
         > <html>
         >   <head>
         >     <title>JavaScript Popup Example</title>
         >     <script type="text/javascript">
         >
         >       function loginCheck(){
         >         //isLoggedIn is a boolean variable you've set to check login
         >         if (isLoggedIn) {  
         >           popup();
         >         }
         >       }
         >       function popon(){
         >         var winOptions = "";
         >         winOptions += "location=1, ";
         >         winOptions += "status=0, ";
         >         winOptions += "scrollbars=0, ";
         >         winOptions += "width=100, ";
         >         winOptions += "height=100";
         >         newWin = window.open(
         >           "index.html", 
         >           "My App's Main Window", 
         >           winOptions
         >         );
         >         newWin.moveTo(400, 300);  //300 pixels down, 
         >                                   //400 pixels to the right
         >       }
         >     </script>
         >   </head>
         >   <body onload="javascript: loginCheck()">
         >     <h1>JavaScript Popup Example</h1>
         >   </body>
         > </html>
         > ```
   2. Or do you want to open `index.html` in a new tab? 
      simply use the `target` attribute in your anchor tag with the value set to `new`, e.g.  `<a target="new"...`
   3. If you are trying to replace index.html/open in the same tab... you don't need to do anything with your `href`
   4. If you want to open the content of app.html WITHIN the app.html page somehow... then you either:

      1. Need to use an iframe (that can already be tagged in the app.html (you don't need to create it dynamically with JavaScript) and load index.html into it OR...
      2. Use AJAX to load the page behind the scenes while app.html is STILL loaded, in the window/tab... without reloading or replacing it.  Once the AJAX request completes, youi would then do something with the HTML from index.html... like:

         - use plain vanilla JavaScript to dynamically create a div (or show a hidden div) and fill it once index.html is loaded.
         - use a (jQuery) widget such as a tab/tab set or accordion and fill it when app.html is loaded